# Print the first column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to print column 1 of this file. I used this command: `awk '{print $1}'` but it just printed the first word of the 1st column.

**DATA**

```
ABC transporters                             ABC transporters
Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism  Alanine, aspartate 
alpha-Linolenic acid metabolism              alpha-Linolenic acid metabolism
Aminoacyl-tRNA biosynthesis                  Aminoacyl-tRNA biosynthesis
Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism  Amino sugar and nucleotide
Arachidonic acid metabolism                  Arachidonic
```

**Output:**

```
ABC
Alanine,
alpha-Linolenic
Aminoacyl-tRNA
Amino
Arachidonic
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ABC transporters
Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism
alpha-Linolenic acid metabolism 
Aminoacyl-tRNA biosynthesis 
Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism 
Arachidonic acid metabolism
```

Comment: What's the definition of a column here ? Is it fixed-width as muru suggests ? It doesn't appear to be delimited by a specific character type

Comment: AWK supports fixed width, too: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I can see is that your columns are delimited by two space.

so with `awk`:

```
awk -F '\\s\\s' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Ravexina thankyou so much query is solved.

Comment: You are welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it's the correct one ;)

Answer (score 14):

Since this seems to be a fixed-width column, you can just `cut` the corresponding characters. The widest column `Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism` seems to be 44 characters wide, so:

```
$ cut -c1-44 foo
ABC transporters
Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism
alpha-Linolenic acid metabolism
Aminoacyl-tRNA biosynthesis
Amino sugar and nucleotide sugar metabolism
Arachidonic acid metabolism
```

Comment: As far as I see, this will leave the output padded to 44 characters.

Comment: If you'd like to strip off the trailing white-space you can pipe the output through something like `grep -oe '^.*\S'` or `sed -re 's/\s+$//'`. Then again you could do this all in one step: `grep -oEe '^.{,43}\S' foo`

Answer (score 2):

As the second column obviously repeats the beginning of the first column, I take this as criterion for the cut with `sed`, thus it does not depend on the column width:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)\(.*\) \1$/\1\2/'
```

First pattern is the repeated part, backreferenced as `\1` at the end of the line. You could add `;s/ *$//` to remove the trailing spaces if they bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon muru's answer that the column is specified with fixed width, using `egrep` command with option `-o` will allow you to print just the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line specified by the search pattern. By default, however, entire line will be printed.

```
$ egrep -o "^.{44}" foo
```